# Chaining promises with parameters?

Tags: angularjs, promise, q, angular-promise

I was wondering if there is a sugar shorthand for the following in AngularJS:

```
$scope.parseSomeString = function (str) {
    console.log(str);
    // ...
};

someService.fnA($scope.arg1) // fnA doesn't return anything
    .then(function () {
        return someService.fnB($scope.arg2, $scope.arg3()) // fnB returns some, e.g. string
    })
    .then($scope.parseSomeString); // this shorthand is great!
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
someService.fnA($scope.arg1)
    .then(someService.fnB($scope.arg2, $scope.arg3())) // but of course, this just calls the function; not good
    .then($scope.parseSomeString); // this shorthand is great!
```

Any way to bind the arguments `$scope.arg2` and `$scope.arg3()` to `fnB`?

Comment: You can also decorate $q and add a `.fcall` construct to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass in a bound function reference with your arguments using [function.bind (*look at support and shim for older browsers*)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to bind the arguments to the function when it is invoked.

```
someService.fnB.bind(this, $scope.arg2, $scope.arg3);
```

You could pass `null` as the first argument as well if you don't need to set a specific context(which you don't, it looks like), if you need you can pass that context as the first argument.

Try:-

```
someService.fnA($scope.arg1)
.then(someService.fnB.bind(this, $scope.arg2, $scope.arg3)) // but of course, this just calls the function; not good
.then($scope.parseSomeString); // this shorthand is great!
```

You could also use [angular.bind](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bind)

```
someService.fnA($scope.arg1)
  .then(angular.bind(this, someService.fnB, $scope.arg2, $scope.arg3))...
```

Similarly you will find similar methods in the libraries you may already been using like Lodash/underscore has [bind](http://lodash.com/docs#bind), jquery has [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) etc..

Comment: Hm, this seems to work; I'm going to use Lo-Dash's `_.bind`. I just wish there was a version without needing `this`.

Comment: @user2857125 Yeah you did not mention you are using lodash/underscore, yes many libraries has their own version of it. jquery has `jquery.proxy`. Everyone takes a context because it is specifically used to create a bound function.

Comment: @user2857125 See my update angular also has one version of it. You could use that as well.